# Use a graphing device to find all solutions of the equation (natural logs) $e^{x^2} − 8 = x^3 − x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$e^{x^2} − 8 = x^3 − x$

What do I do with the $e^{x^2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're meant to use graphic techniques, so graph the LHS as one function and graph the RHS as one function to get (blue is $e^{x^2} - 8$ and red is $x^3 - x$):

[image]

You should be able to see that there are two solutions, $$x \approx -1.38 \quad \text{and} \quad x \approx 1.52$$

Alternatively, you could plot $e^{x^2}$ as one function and $x^3 - x +8$ as another and then see where they intersect, this might be easier to sketch on paper without technology since one is just a cubic and the other a laaarge exponential.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you couldn't solve it directly!

Comment: @TheNewGuy, You're welcome, generally, if they ask you to use graphic techniques it means that it's not solvable directly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The point is you can't solve this directly. To solve this with a graphing calculator, graph the function $f(x)=e^{x^2}-8-x^3+x$ and use whatever the root finding button is.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question says to use the graphing device (such as a graphing calculator), I would use the following form of the equation:
$$e^{x^2}-8=x^3-x \rightarrow e^{x^2}-x^3+x-8=0$$
Most graphing calculators support equations of the form:
$$y(x)=???$$
Which in this case is:
$$y(x)=e^{x^2}-x^3+x-8$$
You can then estimate the roots of the equation graphically. Here is a plot from wolfram alpha, along with approximate numerical zeros:
$$x \approx -1.38157$$
$$x \approx 1.51647$$[image]